# Convert list of strings to list of lists in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of strings in the format:

```
["[[xxx], [yyy]]",
 "[[xxx], [xxx], [yyy]]",
 "[[zzz]]"...
```

But I want it to be in a list of lists in the format:

```
[[[xxx], [yyy]],
 [[xxx], [xxx], [yyy]],
 [[zzz]]...
```

I tried ast, strip and split, etc... but can't seem to get it to work.

**Edit:**
Editing to make more general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval` works for me using it with a list comprehension. Since you have a list of strings, you need to evaluate each one:

```
import ast

[ast.literal_eval(s) for s in l]
```

**result**

```
[[[1, 1, 'D'],
  [2, 5, 'C'],
  [6, 22, 'S'],
  [23, 57, 'C'],
  [58, 59, 'S'],...
```

Answer (score 0):

> converting list of sttrings to list of lists by using 'translate'

```
data = ["[[xxx], [yyy]]", "[[xxx], [xxx], [yyy]]"]
tal = {39: None}
a = str(data).translate(tal)
print(str(data).translate(tal))
```

> result

```
[[[xxx], [yyy]], [[xxx], [xxx], [yyy]]]
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation alongside with your code.